# Make an ImageButton touchable only the first time

Tags: java, libgdx

So i created a button:

```
  tile = new ImageButton(up,null,checked);
  tile.setPosition(x, 800);
  tile.setSize(118,200);
  tile.addListener(new InputListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
      return true;
    }
  });
```

Right now it changes from the up texture to the checked image every time the button is touched. But what I want is that the texture changes to checked ,only the first time the button is touched and becomes "untouchable" after. Is there any way to do this? EventListeners don't have any feature like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageButton` has a method `setTouchable(Touchable touchable)` inherited from Actor. "Determines how touch events are distributed to this actor. Default is Touchable.enabled."

`Touchable` hase three enum constants:

- `childrenOnly`: No touch input events will be received by the actor, but
  children will still receive events.
- `disabled`: No touch input events will be received by the actor or any
  children.
- `enabled`: All touch input events will be received by the actor and any 
  children.

On the first touch call `setTouchable(Touchable.disabled)` on that particular ImageButton

Comment: thanks, I've put setTouchable(Touchable.disabled) on touchUp and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean field at class level e.g.

```
class SomeClass{
   private boolean isTileTouched = false;
}
```

And use that in your `ClickListener`

```
tile.addListener(new InputListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
      if(isTileTouched) return false;
      isTileTouched = true;
      return true;
    }
  });
```

If you have more then one button you might consider using a `Map<String,Boolean>` for the tileId and the value.